# Using array splice to swap out the last value of an array?

Tags: php, arrays, magento, array-splice

I have an array that looks like so:

```
Array ( [0] => Credit Card Type [1] => MasterCard )
Array ( [0] => Credit Card Number [1] => xxxx-1111 )
Array ( [0] => Processed Amount [1] => $106.91 )
Array ( [0] => Transaction Id [1] => 5011056094736597703015 )
Array ( [0] => AVS Response [1] => Z (Street address does not match, but 5-digit postal code matches.) )
Array ( [0] => CVN Response [1] => M (Card verification number matched.) )
Array ( [0] => Merchant Reference Code [1] => 25f11646823dc7488b48c04491335936 )
```

I'm using `print_r(array($_label, $_value));` to display the above.

I want to swap out the Merchant reference code value which is the long alpha numeric number.

This is a magento build so I'm assuming I'd echo

```
$order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->load($orderId);

echo $order->getIncrementId();
```

What will be the most appropriate way to ge the job done?

`array_splice` or `array_push`?

Any help would be greatly appreciated. thank you.

```
<div class="cards-list">
    <?php if (!$this->getHideTitle()): ?>
        <div class="bold"><?php echo $this->escapeHtml($this->getMethod()->getTitle()) ?></div>
        <?php endif;?>
</div>
<?php
    $cards = $this->getCards();
    $showCount = count($cards) > 1;
?>
<?php foreach ($cards as $key => $card): ?>

    <?php if ($showCount): ?>
        <span><?php echo sprintf($this->__('Credit Card %s'), $key + 1); ?></span>
        <?php endif;?>
    <table class="info-table<?php if ($showCount):?> offset<?php endif;?>">
        <tbody>
            <?php foreach ($card as $_label => $_value):?>
                <tr>
                    <td><?php echo $this->escapeHtml($_label)?>:</td>
                    <td><?php echo nl2br(implode($this->getValueAsArray($_value, true), "\n"))?></td>

                </tr>
                <?php endforeach; ?>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
```

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "swap out". Based on your reference to array_splice I assume that you are looking to remove the "Merchant Reference Code" element from your array and add in another element with the order id?

Comment: That is correct @ever.wakeful

Comment: can you please add the code that generated your `$_label` and `$_value`?

Comment: Sure thing @sv3n I'll do that now.

Answer (score 2):

OK, so based on the print_r output that you have provided, I'm going to assume that you are looping through an array that looks like the below and printing the key ($_label) and value ($_value).

```
$data = array(
  'Credit Card Type' => 'MasterCard',
  'Credit Card Number' => 'xxxx-1111',
  'Processed Amount' => '$106.91',
  'Transaction Id'=> '5011056094736597703015',
  'AVS Response' => 'Z (Street address does not match, but 5-digit postal code matches.)',
  'CVN Response' => 'M (Card verification number matched.)',
  'Merchant Reference Code' => '25f11646823dc7488b48c04491335936'
);
```

So why not just unset the Merchant Reference Code key and add what ever key/value you want into the array. eg:

```
unset($data['Merchant Reference Code']);
$data['Order Id'] = $order->getIncrementId();
```

Comment: When i test it with the code above it breaks the bottom half of the page. Maybe I did something wrong?

Comment: I guess it depends on where you added that code. Its hard to tell with only parts of the code you are working on. Where do you call Mage::getModel('sales/order')->load($orderId); ?

Answer (score 1):

I think you can replace:

```
<?php foreach ($card as $_label => $_value):?>
<tr>
    <td><?php echo $this->escapeHtml($_label)?>:</td>
    <td><?php echo nl2br(implode($this->getValueAsArray($_value, true), "\n"))?></td>

</tr>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

with:

```
<?php foreach ($card as $_label => $_value): ?>
<?php if ($_label === 'Merchant Reference Code') {
    continue;
} ?>
<tr>
    <td><?php echo $this->escapeHtml($_label)?>:</td>
    <td><?php echo nl2br(implode($this->getValueAsArray($_value, true), "\n"))?></td>

</tr>
<?php endforeach; ?>
<tr>
    <td>Order ID:</td>
    <td><?php echo $order->getIncrementId();?></td>
</tr>
```

***Note:*** maybe add `$this->__()` to translate "Order ID" and "Merchant Reference Code"

---

**Edit:** to answer comment

If you template block class inherits from `Mage_Core_Block_Abstract` you can use `$this->__('some String)` to use Magentos default method to translate something.

So first thing is to replace

```
<?php if ($_label === 'Merchant Reference Code') {
```

With

```
<?php if ($_label === $this->__('Merchant Reference Code')) {
```

This makes this this check language indepented from being tranlated to the customers language. For german language it would be translated first to `<?php if ($_label === Refferenz Code) {` and it would still work. Same for "Order Id:".

To support different languages ...

- add `My_Module.csv` to `app/locale/{LANG_ISO}/` with

  ```
  "Merchant Reference Code";"Translate string"
  ```
- make tranlation file available in `app/code/{pool}/My/Module/ect/config.xml` add this to `global`, `frontend` or `adminhtml` section

  ```
  <translate>
      <modules>
          <My_Module>
              <files>
                  <default>My_Module.csv</default>
              </files>
          </My_Module>
      </modules>
  </translate>
  ```
- add helper to "enable" translations, add this to `app/code/{pool}/My/Module/Helpers/Data.php`

  ```
  class My_Module_Helper_Data extends Mage_Core_Helper_Abstract
  {
      protected $_moduleName = 'My_Module';
  }
  ```

Comment: It's breaking the page. Explain the last part $this->__() please.